# Continuous image pan based on mouse location

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover, pan

I have a seamless background image that I am looking to influence based on the location of the cursor relative to the centerline.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgixq.jpg)

The further to the sides of the screen, the faster the horizontal pan would accelerate (and continue looping infinitely). Inversely, the closer to center, the more stationary the image would become.

Thanks!

Current attempts can only pan single image following cursor movement

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example